# How to pass data into options in <Form.Select> </Form.Select> with Semantic UI React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a list of items. Items are fetched dynamically from an API and need to display in `<select/>`
I'm using semantic-ui react components.

options accepts an object in the form:
`{ key: "", text: "", value: "" }`

This is the form:

```html
<Form size="large">
  <Form.Select
    fluid
    label="Application Name"
    name="appName"
    onChange={(event) => fetchHandler(event)}
    options={} --> Item to be passed
  />
</Form>
```

This is what I tried:
Here options is the response and I'm adding a item  `appName` into a list `appNames`.

```
let appNames = [];
options.map((value) => {
  value.map((app) => {
    return appNames.push(app.appName);
  });
});

const appNameHandler = () => {
  let appOptions = [
    {
      key: '',
      text: '',
      value: '',
    },
  ];
  for (let key = 0; key >= appNames.length; key++) {
    appOptions.push(...appNames, {
      key: key,
      text: appNames,
      value: appNames,
    });
  }
  console.log(appOptions);
  return appOptions;
};
```

Is there any better workaround for this?

Comment: it's hard to help with your code being disconnected in several places. What do you actually put into the `options` parameter in the Select? what is `options` in the JS code you show? where is appNameHandler called? what's that weird call to `.push` where you are add all appNames as many times as there are elements in that array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little hard to tell what you are doing, but I would do it like this

```js
const appNames = [];
options.forEach((value) => {
  value.forEach((app, index) => {
    appNames.push({
       key: index,
       text: app.appName,
       value: app.appName,
    });
  });
});
```

and then pass appNames to options.

No need to use 'map' if you aren't using the returned array.